# How to detect if button is clicked unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not sure how to test if a button is clicked in unity 19.4. This is the code I tested does anyone know how to test things in the Update Method?

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{

[Header("Button Objects")]
    public Button buttonOne;

void Update()
    {
        if (buttonOne.clicked == true)
        {

            Debug.Log("It worked :D");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version specifically of Unity are you using? I know they've introduced a new UI system in newer versions where adding an onclick is now different. When you say 19.4, is that 2019.4?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) or [`Button.onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons work by adding listeners to the event of their [`onclick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html). These listeners can be persistent or runtime listeners. Persistent listeners are assigned in the editor and the runtime listeners are assigned in code at runtime. Here is how you would assign a new listener in code.

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Button btn = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // adding a delegate with no parameters
        btn.onClick.AddListener(NoParamaterOnclick);
           
        // adding a delegate with parameters
        btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate{ParameterOnClick("Button was pressed!");});
    }
    
    private void NoParamaterOnclick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Button clicked with no parameters");
    }
    
    private void ParameterOnClick(string test)
    {
        Debug.Log(test);
    }
}
```

In the above example, I am adding two listeners. I am not sure if the function you want to call will have parameters or not, so make sure to only add a single callback unless you want multiple functions called when your button is clicked.

[`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) is a method that is called every frame. Only put logic in here that is continually checked or updated often. A button should only react once it is clicked, which is why it has the `onclick`. Unity is already internally checking if a button is clicked by using its `EventSystem` and a series of `GraphicalRaycasts`.

I had asked which version of Unity you are in as in newer versions there is a newer UI flow called [`UI Builder`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ui.builder@1.0/manual/index.html) which has a [`completely different method`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-builder-how-to-make-buttons-interactable.786701/) of adding onclick events.

Comment: Thank you for the help.